# CORS. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, php, http, https

I try to get data from API and get this error:

`Access to fetch at '..../get-setting' from origin 'http://localhost:63342' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Header that return this API in Postman:

[Postman Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hr7Jd.png)

Code of my response:

```
 fetch('.../get-setting', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Basic ${credentials}`,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
```

I don't know, problem in API or in my code. I want to know what I did wrong. And what I need to do to fix this problem.

Comment: You do **not** set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in your AJAX code - that header is set by the server in response to your request.